# Can I use api-platform/admin on its own for a OpenAPI endpoint?

Tags: api-platform.com

https://github.com/api-platform/admin/blob/master/README.md says the OpenAPI documentation, so I've just tried to get it up and running for a local (non API-platform) project. I've tried the following

```js
import React from "react";
import { HydraAdmin } from "@api-platform/admin";

export default () => (
  <HydraAdmin entrypoint="http://192.168.1.2:3000/openapi.json" />
);
```

And some attempts with public endpoints, but I'm not really getting anywhere. I keep getting errors like this

```
Error: Cannot fetch documentation: 200

in AdminGuesser (created by AdminGuesserWithError)
in ErrorBoundary (created by AdminGuesserWithError)
in TranslationProvider (created by AdminGuesserWithError)
in AdminGuesserWithError (created by HydraAdmin)
in HydraAdmin (at App.js:5)
in Unknown (at src/index.js:9)
in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

Which is totally fine if api-platform/admin is only supposed to be used with api-platform :) So just to make sure before I try to dig any futher - is connecting the admin to a random OpenAPI 
 endpoint a supported usecase? And if so, how do I go about getting the app bootstrapped?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot without some additional developments.

Api Platform admin is designed to use [Hydra Documentations](http://www.hydra-cg.com/).

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/api-platform/admin/issues/161) to add OpenApi support, but it seems dead right now.